# Show that for all $a,b,c$ positive real numbers that $(a+b+c)(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})\geq 9$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for all $a ,b , c $ positive real numbers that

$$(a + b + c)(a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1})⩾ 9 $$

Comment: AM-HM Inequality or Cauchy Scwarz inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Are you aware of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

If you take $x = (\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c})$ and $y = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\|x\|\|y\|\geq|\langle x,y\rangle|
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, a lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that this is an exercise given to students in introductory courses such as number theory or discrete mathematics that have taken non-proof based calculus. If that's the case, I will give a proof which doesn't rely on Cauchy-Schwarz or the AM-GM inequality.

**Lemma:** For every positive real number $x$, we have $x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$.

**Proof:** Using Calculus, we take the derivative of the function $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ to obtain $f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}$. The critical values are thus $1, 0,$ and $-1$, and it is easy to show that $f(x)$ has a local minimum at $x  = 1$ $(f(1) = 2)$. Since we need not consider negative values of $x$, we can conclude the result.

So now we are ready to tackle the main question in this post: showing $(a+b+c)(a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1}) \geq 9$.

**Proof**: We observe that if we simply expand $(a+b+c)(a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1})$ we obtain $$(a+b+c)(a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1}) = 3 + (ab^{-1} + a^{-1}b) + (a^{-1}c + ac^{-1}) + (cb^{-1} + c^{-1}b)$$

Then, we note that if we let $x = ab^{-1}$, we have $(ab^{-1} + a^{-1}b) = x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ by our lemma. We can argue in exactly the same way to show that $(a^{-1}c + ac^{-1}) \geq 2$ and $(cb^{-1} + c^{-1}b) \geq 2$. Thus, we obtain $$3 + (ab^{-1} + a^{-1}b) + (a^{-1}c + ac^{-1}) + (cb^{-1} + c^{-1}b) \geq 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 9$$ as desired.

Comment: I don't think calculus is more "elementary" than these inequalities. In this sense, the inequality $x+\frac 1x\ge 2$ could be explained by the fact that $(a-b)^2\ge 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's another approach. First, multiply the left side all out, to get
3 + a/b + b/a + a/c + c/a + b/c + c/b.  Now consider a/b + b/a. Making a common demonimator, we get $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab} $. Next we note that $(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab$, so $a^2 + b^2 = (a-b)^2 + 2ab.$  Putting that over ab, we get $\frac{(a-b)^2 + 2ab}{ab} > 2$.  Repeat this for the other pairs, and we get the result.